# Count commits since last change to file

Tags: git, commit, git-commit, counting

I'm currently working on a system that automatically increments a version number. The version number is currently stored in a file using a major, minor and patch version. I thought about getting rid of the patch to prevent having to manually change the version number each time.
The patch would then simply be the number of commits since the last time the file (or the version if that works too) was changed.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

yeah we can list the all the commits made to the specific file. **git log --follow filename** but i am not sure about the count.

Comment: This works: ``git rev-list --count $(git log --follow -1 --pretty=%H filename)..HEAD``

Comment: @BrainStone: Note that this method can work well, but you must be ready for cases where the count "jumps up" due to merges. The `X..Y` notation means "the set of commits reachable from `Y` minus the set reachable from `X`". Normally, adding 1 commit to the set in `Y` adds 1 to the resulting count—but when you add a *merge* commit to `Y` you will generally add much more than 1. This is fine *as long as* you don't expect it to only increment one at a time. (The commits brought in on the "other side" of the merge remain in, so the count increases again from there.)

Comment: @torek this is what I want. So it's fine